# How to avoid explicit return in scala

Tags: scala

I have this method, given a sequence of instruments, it queries a web service to get the old price and the new price. Then it will use a function to see if the price difference is significant. It will return the first instrument with a significant price difference. 
Now, my problem is it always returns None unless I add an explicit return statement as below.

I understand scala returns the last expression to be evaluated. Is there a way to refactor this code to avoid an explicit return.

In what situations we cannot avoid having explicit return statements?

```
// without explicit return

def findEquty[A](instruments: Seq[A], change: (Double, Double) => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  for (instrument <- instruments) {
    val oldPrice = getOldPrice(instrument)
    val newPrice = getNewPrice(instrument)
    if (change(oldPrice, newPrice)) Some(instrument)
  }
  None
}

// with explicit return

def findEquty[A](instruments: Seq[A], change: (Double, Double) => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  for (instrument <- instruments) {
    val oldPrice = getOldPrice(instrument)
    val newPrice = getNewPrice(instrument)
    if (change(oldPrice, newPrice)) return Some(instrument)
  }
  None
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation (without the `return` statement) contains two *expressions*:

- The first is the `for` expression, which has the type `Unit`: that's the return type of a for expression without `yield` (it's interpreted as a call to `Seq.foreach` which returns `Unit`)
- The second is simply `None`

Every code block in Scala evaluates to the *last* expression in that block; Therefore, in this case, the entire method body necessarily evaluates into `None`.

Adding the `return` statement causes the method to return before reaching this expression (under certain circumstances), hence the "correct" result.

You can solve this by using the more concise `find`, which does exactly what you need - finds the first element matching a given predicate, or `None` if none found:

```
def findEquty[A](instruments: Seq[A], change: (Double, Double) => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  instruments.find(instrument => {
    val oldPrice = getOldPrice(instrument)
    val newPrice = getNewPrice(instrument)
    change(oldPrice, newPrice)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For loops return a `Unit`, meaning they are only executed for their side effects, that is why it doesn't return a value unless you do it explicitly.

You should use the [find method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]) which a returns an option with the first element matches the given predicate:

```
def findEquty[A](instruments: Seq[A], change: (Double, Double) => Boolean): Option[A] = 
  instruments.find {
    val oldPrice = getOldPrice(instrument)
    val newPrice = getNewPrice(instrument)
    change(oldPrice, newPrice)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A general technique is simply defining your operation over the whole collection and using laziness to only do the amount of work necessary to get a result.

You can filter and get the first element of the result. If you use an Iterator, or possibly a Stream, you prevent doing too much work.

```
instruments.iterator.filter { instrument =>
  val oldPrice = getOldPrice(instrument)
  val newPrice = getNewPrice(instrument)
  change(oldPrice, newPrice)
}.buffered.headOption
```